# calculated on (the \ an) anhydrous, solvent-free basis - which article to use?

Tags: articles

> 1. calculated on **an** anhydrous, solvent-free basis
> 2. ... calculated on **the** anhydrous, solvent-free basis

I came across two variations of the phrase, with **an** and with **the**:

> [image]

("Analytical Profiles of Drug Substances and Excipients" by Klaus Florey)

and

> [image]

("Profiles of Drug Substances, Excipients and Related Methodology, book 39" by Harry G. Brittain)

Why is **an** used in the first sentence and **the** in the second? Does the first version imply that the calculation can be performed using several different techniques?

Comment: It just depends on whether ***anhydrous, solvent-free*** is a "known" basis for such calculations or not. If this method is already familiar to the target readership, ***or*** has been specifically introduced as a possible method within your text, you can use ***the*** (but you don't *have* to; you could still use ***an***). If not, you shouldn't use ***the***. You should also stick to ***an*** if you want to imply that more than one different method could be referred to by this expression.

Comment: **an anhydrous basis** implies that there are multiple anhydrous bases, and the measurement is being calculated on one such substance. The second implies that the specific rotation is calculated on a substance which will be an anhydrous basis, and **the** refers to the one you have, as in a recipe: "Sift *the* whole-wheat flour".

Comment: It may be due to the different sources that you get the different articles.

Comment: An alternate understanding of **the** in the second one, is that attention is being drawn specifically to the fact that the basis is anhydrous and solvent-free, again as in a recipe:  "Stir in the peeled and blanched carrots", that is, *the carrots which have been peeled and blanched*.  This refers to a previous instruction in the recipe to peel and blanch the carrots, or in your case, either to a previous instruction that the basis be anhydrous and solvent-free or to a generally known fact that the basis must be anhydrous and solvent-free.

Comment: The first one is a report on an experiment that was performed, the second is a description of a methodology for a procedure. There is a convention that many hold to in science that when writing a report a passive voice should be used so "an reactant was used" is preferred to "the reactant was used".

Comment: I think it is just an authors' interpretation of whether a *basis* is unique or not. You would have to ask the authors, unless you have specific technical expertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nouns in English, if singular, concrete, not in certain prepositional phrases, and not proper, must have a determiner.  Articles are determiners - and what determiners do answer the question "which X?".

*A/An X* is telling the reader/listener it doesn't matter which X and possibly that the reader/listener should choose an applicable X.

*The X* is telling the reader/listener you expect him/her to know which X already - either because you mentioned it, you both observed  it, or everyone knows about it or can see it.  It can additionally imply the reader has chosen that specific X versus other possible X's.

> ... calculated on the anhydrous and solvent-free basis.

So this can mean:

- there is a well-known basis called "anhydrous and solvent-free" that everyone - including you - should know about already.
- use the anhydrous and solvent-free basis versus another possible basis.